# How to get whitespace using jQuery's .html() or .text()

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div> </span>
<span>  </span>
```

How can I get an `.innerHTML` (or `.innerText`) including the original whitespace? I tried jQuery's `.html()` and `.text()`, but they return an empty string.

Comment: What browser are you using?  This is working fine on FF7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use .contents() then get the nodeValue...
something like this,

```
$('span').contents()[0].nodeValue
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/GnZur/)

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that HTML ignores continuous whitespace. So if you have more than 1, it won't show up. If the jQuery .html() method isn't working for you (maybe they trim inside), you could also just get at the same inner html directly

```
alert($('#div').get(0).innerHTML)
```

Comment: innerHTML is not supported by latest browsers now a days... Firefox5 doesnt allow using innerHTML

Comment: innerHTML is supported by all browsers, I don't think your statement is true.

Comment: I'm sure you're mistaken. jQuery uses innerHTML internally, it's a part of the DOM. If you run this example in your browser you'll see it works : http://jsfiddle.net/TP7yU/ (tried on FF7)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the non-breaking space html entity for each space you need.

```
&nbsp;
```

More about html entities - 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

Empty whitespace longer than one space in HTML is treated like empty string - no data. I think you will need to use &nbsp; to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is white space insensititive . Would wrapping it in pre block work at all?

```
<pre>       </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried using following code and it works- i can see a whitespace added in input box

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  alert($(".d").text());
  $("#a").val($(".d").text());
});

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="d"> </span>
<span class="c">  </span>
<input id="a"/>
```